# Cannot insert data with pry, but console works. Only on one table. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sql-insert, rails-console, pry

I'm trying to create a new category inside my pry console and get this error:

```
$ pry -r ./config/environment
[1] pry(main)> cat = Category.create(name: "Programming")
Error: Cannot open "/Users/johncurry/Desktop/programs/startup/jetpack/=" for reading.
```

But when I try to add data in a different table it works just fine. for example

```
$ user = User.create(username: "Jello")
```

This will insert into the user table. (still in pry.)

When I switch to Rails Console it works.

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> cat = Category.create(name: "Programming")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (14.1ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" etc...
```

So I feel like it's safe to assume this is a PRY issue since my database is there, it works in Rails console, and even works inside of the pry console, with the exception of my categories table. I Haven't found any issues even remotely similar on S.O.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons pry is so powerful is because it has a lot of commands. In this case, `cat` is one of them. There's also `cd`, `edit`, `ls`, `cat` in pry, so if you try to name your variables the same, it won't be happy about it.